# file not uploading in codeigniter api

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter

I want to upload picture in my uploads folder, I am trying to upload picture using codeigniter upload library but **I am facing this error**. please check my code and guide me .

```
 **Array
(
[0] => <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>
)**
```

but when i `print_r($_FILES)` postman gives me the file but not upload in uploads folder.this is **print_r result:**

```
    Array
(
[image] => Array
(
[name] => 1578767846S
[type] => i
[tmp_name] => /
[error] =>
[size] =>
)

)
```

**this is my code for my controller:**

```
public function product_add_post(){

     $data=array(
     'pname'=>$this->input->post('title'),
     'pprice'=>$this->input->post('price'),
     'battery'=>$this->input->post('battery'),
     'lcd'=>$this->input->post('lcd'),

     'camera'=>$this->input->post('camera'),
     'speaker'=>$this->input->post('speaker'),
    'speaker'=>$this->input->post('speaker'),
     'city'=>$this->input->post('city'),
     'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
    'pstatus'=>1,
    'verifystatus'=>0,
    'userid'=>$this->input->post('userid'),
    'pdate'=>date('d/m/y'),
    'cid'=>$this->input->post('cat_id'),
     );

     $p_id=$this->product_model->save_product($data);
     //===================================
     //        uploading img1
     //===================================


     if($p_id){


     $config = array();
                $config['upload_path'] ='./uploads' ;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
                $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;


                $this->load->library('upload');
                $files = $_FILES;

                $inserted = "";
                if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {

                    $new_image_name = array();
                    $files = $_FILES;

                    $count = count($_FILES['image']['name']);

                    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                        $_FILES['image']['name'] = $new_image_name = time() . str_replace(str_split(' ()\\/,:*?"<>|'), '', $files['image']['name'][$i]);
                        $_FILES['image']['type'] = $files['image']['type'][$i];
                        $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] = $files['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
                        $_FILES['image']['error'] = $files['image']['error'][$i];
                        $_FILES['image']['size'] = $files['image']['size'][$i];

                        $this->upload->initialize($config);

                        if(! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
        {
              $msg[]=$this->upload->display_errors();
              print_r($msg);exit;
        }

                        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

                        $name_array[] = $upload_data['file_name'];
                        $fileName = $upload_data['file_name'];
                        $images[] =$fileName;
                        $pImage['pid'] = $p_id;
                        $pImage['imagename'] = base_url('uploads/').$images[$i];

                        $pImage['date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                    $inserted = $this->product_model->addimage($pImage);

                    }

                     $this->response( $inserted, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
                }

 }
```

}

Comment: have you got `$_FILES` array on a controller? have done `print_r` in the controller

Comment: Do you have `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in `<form>`?